# How to add link to API results

Tags: javascript, json

I have created a gallery which pulls the pictures randomly from API (picsum.photos)
Check it out here: https://codepen.io/lucas-knm/pen/oVmmEV

The problem is those two links are not clickable. I need to change them with a text or an icon and have them linked to the the actual address in a new page.

I tried this code which obviously would not work:

here is the Full Js Code :

```
window.onload = init;
function init(){

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open("GET", "https://picsum.photos/list", true);

        xhr.send(null);

        xhr.onload = function(){

                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var picsum = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                    console.log(picsum);

                var imageString = "";
                    for(var x = 500; x <510; x++){
                    imageString +=  "<div class = imgContainer>" + "<p class = author>" + 
                    picsum[x].author
                    + 
                    "</p>"
                    + 
                    "<img src= 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image='>"
                    + 
                    "<p class = authorUrl>" 
                    + 
                    picsum[x].author_url
                    + 
                    "</p><p class = postUrl>"
                    + 
                    picsum[x].post_url
                    + 
                    "</p>"  
                    +
                    "</div>"    
                                    }
                document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = imageString;
                gallery.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 12px; text-align: left; display:absolute;');

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of writing the URLs in text format, you have to crate `<a>` tag and set the URLs as the `href` attribute of them:

```
window.onload = init;
function init(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "https://picsum.photos/list", true);

    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onload = function(){

            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                var picsum = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
                console.log(picsum);

            var imageString = "";
                for(var x = 500; x <510; x++){
                imageString +=  "<div class = imgContainer>" + "<p class = author>" + 
                picsum[x].author
                + 
                "</p>"
                + 
                "<img src= 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image='>"
                + 
                "<p class = authorUrl>" 
                + 
                //This is what you need:
                "<a href='" + picsum[x].author_url + "'>"+ picsum[x].author_url +"</a>";
                + 
                "</p><p class = postUrl>"
                + 
                "<a href='" +  picsum[x].post_url + "'>"+  picsum[x].post_url +"</a>"

                + 
                "</p>"  
                +
                "</div>"    
                                }
            document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = imageString;
            gallery.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 12px; text-align: left; display:absolute;');

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the pictures loaded as body background when user clicks on each image?

Comment: Yes. What you need is to re-generate the html and onclick etc. you always use to handel events. for example you may generate `<a onclick="setBg('imagURL')">` and also write a function name it `setBg` to get the `imageURL` as parameter and set it as background. @VortexIT

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the link in `<a>` tag:

```
window.onload = init;
function init() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "https://picsum.photos/list", true);

  xhr.send(null);

  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      var picsum = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      console.log(picsum);

      var imageString = "";
      for (var x = 500; x < 510; x++) {
        imageString +=
          "<div class = 'imgContainer'>" +
          "<p class = 'author'>" +
          picsum[x].author +
          "</p>" +
          "<img src= 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?image='>" +
          "<p class = 'authorUrl'><a href=" +
          picsum[x].author_url +
          " target='_blank'>" +
          picsum[x].author_url +
          "</a></p><p class = 'postUrl'><a href=" +
          picsum[x].post_url +
          " target='_blank'>" +
          picsum[x].post_url +
          "</p>" +
          "</div>";
      }
      document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML = imageString;
      gallery.setAttribute(
        "style",
        "font-size: 12px; text-align: left; display:absolute;"
      );
    }
  };
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/armenbadalyan/pen/QoYoja)